# TSAgg R package error message: namespace ‘memoise’ is not available

Tags: r, memoise

I am trying to use the TSAgg package to aggregate my data over days. However, I get a the following error message:

```
> Data.1day<-daysAgg(Data.ts,mean)
Warning: namespace ‘memoise’ is not available and has been replaced
by .GlobalEnv when processing object ‘sep’
Warning: namespace ‘memoise’ is not available and has been replaced
by .GlobalEnv when processing object ‘sep’
Error in .get_loc_regs(locale) : could not find function "digest"
```

When I loaded TSAgg, there was the following warning message:
Warning messages:

```
1: package ‘TSAgg’ was built under R version 3.0.2 
2: package ‘lubridate’ was built under R version 3.0.2
```

I am using R version 3.0.1 as I don't want to use a test build. Is there anything I can do to make it work?

Comment: This is a wild guess, but try `install.packages("memoise")`. `lubridate` depends on the package `memoise`, so it may be that that dependency wasn't correctly installed for you (for whatever reason).